# How to extract specific dictionary based on specific keys using regex?

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I have data in the form of dictionaries with the number of key-value pairs varying in each dictionary. I am trying to extract only specific dictionaries based on the specific keys (to extract only those dictionaries that have the keys "A", "B" and "C", not more nor less).

I tried this code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(\{\"A"\:(.*?\)\,\"B"\:(.*?\)\,\"C"\:(.*\)\})')
test_str = {"A":2.3,"B":3,"C":2.9},{"A":2.1,"B":33,"C":1.2,"D":9,"F":3.4},{"A":1.4,"B":3.3,"C":1.6,"G":3.2,"K":4},
        {"A":4.3,"B":11,"C":93}
for match in re.findall(pattern, test_str):
print(match)
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Input:

```
{"A":2.3,"B":3,"C":2.9},{"A":2.1,"B":33,"C":1.2,"D":9,"F":3.4},{"A":1.4,"B":3.3,"C":1.6,"G":3.2,"K":4},
        {"A":4.3,"B":11,"C":93}
```

Expected Output:

```
{"A":2.3,"B":3,"C":2.9},{"A":4.3,"B":11,"C":93}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with *regex*?! Your `test_str` doesn't appear to be a string, it's a tuple of dictionaries. If it's JSON, parse it; this is a much easier operation to do on a sequence of dictionaries than a string, you can just do e.g. `set(d.keys()) == {"a", "b", "c"}`.

Comment: Same question here: Are we talking about a string with a list of python type dictionaries or about a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think that `set` is necessary as keys should be unique, but as dictionaries are not sorted, a `sorted` may be a good idea?

Comment: @mikuszefski it's not necessary in Python 3, where a `dict_keys` object is already comparable to a `set` of the same values, but in Python 2 the keys are a list, so creating the set makes it order-independent (and at `O(n)` more efficiently than the `O(n log n)` sort). It's not to make them unique (as you say, they must be already).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually the actual data is much more complicated than the one i have mentioned , the data is in string format .Even converting into json format and parsing it requires plenty of regular expression to make it into correct format. Thus, Opting for regex to scrap the relevant information first.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was expecting something like this. But is it `O(n)` if you have to compare two "unsorted" sets?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes 0(n). (in the original data "A" and "B" represent latitude and longitude value , sorting will mess with the trajectory ). Unstructured Data

Comment: @mikuszefski sorting doesn't matter, sets work on the hashes (like dictionaries, they're basically dictionaries without values) so lookups are O(1). If you imagine it as `for item in first_set: if item in second_set:` it should be O(n) overall.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] that actually recreates the underlying problem? This is likely an XY problem, there may be much better overall solutions than mangling strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was trying out different regex, as of now this one seems to be working fine:

```
r'({\"A\"\:[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\,\"B\":[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\,\"C\"\:[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*})
```